# OpenGL: How do I map a square texture onto a rectangular surface?

Tags: opengl, textures, graphics, geometry, graphics-programming

I'm not asking about how to map the texture itself. I'm just wondering how I could go about evenly mapping a texture to an object so that it repeats itself instead of stretching to the surface.

For example:
[image: A rectangle with the texture stretching to each corner, and a rectangle with the texture repeated without losing its original aspect ratio.]

Thanks.

Comment: make texture coordinates to be bigger than 1, for example 2 and calculate that by using the sideratio of the rectangle.

Comment: How are you creating this object and assigning textures to it? Is it made by hand in a 3D tool where you can manually adjust the UV coordinates? Or is it generated/modified at runtime in a way that your texture mapping needs to react to?

Comment: @DMGregory I'm setting all the data (position + uv) manually, in the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you're spawning a quad with `width` and `height`

and you want your texture to spawn its entire height exactly once

and you want the width to truncate/repeat accordingly to preserve the texture aspect ratio

then you want your UV x values to run from `0` to `width/height`

and your UV y values to run from `0` to `1`

This way if `width` is twice as large as `height`, your texture will tile two times horizontally. And correspondingly for other sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the wrapping mode:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);    
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

You can also do

```
GL_CLAMP
GL_REPEAT
GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT
GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDR
GL_MIRROR_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
```

See [What does changing GL_TEXTURE_WRAP)_(S/T) do?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/62548/what-does-changing-gl-texture-wrap-s-t-do) for more info

Comment: I'm aware of the various wrap modes. My question was about how to set the texture coordinates in such a way that the image would retain its aspect ratio, instead of stretching to the shape of what I'm drawing.

Comment: I believe you would have to get the dimensions of the triangle being rendered (in 3d space) and then scale that with the dimensions of your texture

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml - the default is GL_REPEAT so it doesn't need to be explicitly set.

Answer (score 0):

First set the wrap mode:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);    
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

Then you just need to make your texture coordinates bigger than 1.

Instead of putting 1, 1, you need to put 2, 2 and it will repeat itself twice. Good luck!